Непонятен принцип работы алгоритма для инверсии строки в C
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_reverse(char *s)
{
        size_t len = strlen(s);
        char *t = s + len - 1;
        while (t >= s) {
                printf("%c", *t);
                t -= 1;
        }
        puts("");
}

int main()
{
        char *s = "1234567";
        print_reverse(s);
        return 0;
}     

почему мы прибавляем к массиву char число, что вообще здесь происходит?

Не к массиву, а к указателю. Адресная арифметика

то есть, в данном случае это адрес 1-го элемента. Спасибо за помощь!

К указателю прибавляется длина строки, и отнимается единица чтобы указатель указывал на последний символ строки, а арифметика предполагает сдвиг адреса вперёд на указанное число, т е. его увеличение. Аналогия &s[len - 1]
